# How to get cython and gensim to work with pyspark

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, cython, gensim

I'm running a Lubuntu 16.04 Machine with `gcc` installed. I'm not getting `gensim` to work with `cython` because when I train a `doc2vec model`, it is only ever trained with one worker which is dreadfully slow.

As I said `gcc` was installed from the start. I then maybe made the mistake and installed `gensim` before `cython`. I corrected that by forcing a reinstall of `gensim` via `pip`. With no effect still just one worker.

The machine is setup as a `spark` master and I interface with `spark` via `pyspark`.  It works something like this, `pyspark` uses `jupyter` and `jupyter` uses python 3.5. This way I get a `jupyter` interface to my cluster. Now I have no idea if this is the reason why i cant get `gensim` to work with `cython`. I don't execute any gensim code on the cluster, it is just more convenient to fire up `jupyter` to also do `gensim`.

Comment: As far as I can tell from the gensim page, it has nothing to do with Cython. What exactly are you doing, and what makes you think that Cython and gensim go together?

Comment: A closer look suggests that gensim does have some optional faster versions written in Cython, but you shouldn't need Cython yourself to install it (the generated C file looks to be supplied so that you only need GCC). It also looks to provide a warning on installation if you can't build the C modules and a warning on import if you don't have the C modules. Do you get any of those warnings?

Comment: I read in the word2vec tutorial: _The workers parameter has only effect if you have Cython installed. Without Cython, you’ll only be able to use one core because of the GIL (and word2vec training will be miserably slow)._ [here](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/) and no I don't get any any build errors at least not when I do it via pip.

Comment: Also there is a comment in the source about it: _This is the non-optimized, Python version. If you have cython installed, gensim will use the optimized version from word2vec_inner instead._ [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/a18b3df11564d3c3abbb7dba740ecc1fef5f29ce/gensim/models/word2vec.py)

Comment: I'd try two things: 1) search gensim directories for .so files (it should generate some all being well); 2) Reinstall it using `-v` on the command line (I think it swallows most messages by default unfortunately, and this gets it back) and have a close look at the output. (I think that's all the suggestions I can give)

Comment: Everything is there and I reinstalled with verbose on. No errors also `gensim.models.doc2vec.FAST_VERSION` is `1`. So everything should work fine. Still the python thread only utilizes ~170% CPU performance of 1200% (12 Cores) possible. Performance also seems not to be disk bound Iotop, show little to no disk activity. So maybe it is memory bound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deeper and trying things like loading the whole corpus into memory executing gensim in a different environment etc. all with no effect. It seems it is a problem with gensim that the code is only partial parallelized. This results in the workers not being able to fully utilize the CPU. See the issues on github [link](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/532).

Comment: I can only do that after 1 hour

Answer (score 0):

You probably did this, but could you please check that you are using the parallel Cythonised version by `assert gensim.models.doc2vec.FAST_VERSION > -1` ?

The gensim doc2vec code is parallelized but unfortunately the I/O code that is outside of Gensim isn't. For example, in the [github issue](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/532#issuecomment-251474530) you linked parallelization is indeed achieved after the corpus is loaded into RAM by `doclist = [doc for doc in documents]`

Comment: as I stated above I did all of this with no avail