# Couldn't parallelize my execution of word2vec using gensim

Tags: python, cython, gensim

I wanted to parallelize the word2vec execution with gensim. Well, let me describe what are the steps I have done:

1. Have installed c compiler using minGW and set the Env variable path
2. Then I downloaded the .tar.gz file of gensim-2.1.0 and installed gensim through CMD with command "python setup.py install"
3. Gensim got installed without any error
4. My Python version, Gensim FAST_VERSION result is as below:

[Python, Gensim, FAST_VERSION screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nk70.jpg)

N.B: I am using the versions: Windows 7, Python version 2.7.13, gensim version 2.1.0, scipy version 0.18.1

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42039964/how-to-get-cython-and-gensim-to-work-with-pyspark

Comment: And if so you should edit your question to confirm some of thing things discussed in that question: the value of `gensim.models.word2vec.FAST_VERSION`, the presence or absence of the compiled modules (.pyd files), and the results of reinstalling it with the verbose flag. Beyond that I know almost nothing about gensim so can't personally help further, but hopefully someone else can if you can provide more detailed information

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [Cython windows support page](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/CythonExtensionsOnWindows)? The error you gave a screenshot of is Cython-related. I am not sure but Anaconda may expect C compiler presence.